# How do I stop non-network entries from showing in DevTools network tab?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, svg, devtools

For the site I'm working on, in the Chrome DevTools network tab I often get over 100 identical requests for the same SVG check mark image. It looks like this:

[image: many loads for svg]

They are not actually requesting anything from a server.

Is my page doing something it shouldn't? If it is, how do I fix it? If it isn't, how do I make these things stop cluttering up my network tab WITHOUT removing actual network requests?

I did a lot of googling to try to figure this out and wasted a lot of time before I came up with a reasonable answer. I'm posting this along with my answer for others, and just in case someone has a better answer.

Comment: Sounds like you should [report this as a bug here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/)

Comment: It seems probable that this is the intended behavior, even though I don't like it, but I suppose eve if it is it still might be worth telling them that it seems wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The page might not be doing anything wrong, though it is possible that it is using an SVG more times than expected and/or necessary. I'm not sure if it is slowing the page load or causing other issues but if so, it is currently too small to notice.

The clutter that this SVG causes in the network tab of Chrome's DevTools can be filtered out with the "Hide data URLs" checkbox. If you don't see the checkbox, you must first click the filter button (which looks like a funnel, and shows up near "Preserve log" for me).

[image]

The SVGs are being generated using [Data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs). In CSS, Data URLs allow you to generate content in places where you can use a url, such as here:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 16 16'%3e%3cpath fill='none' stroke='%23343a40' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-linejoin='round' stroke-width='2' d='m2 5 6 6 6-6'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
```

This is the actual code that was creating that SVG checkbox in the question. This is useful but somewhat confusing because it isn't a URL (as most people use the term, and hopefully also in technical terms but I don't know). It doesn't refer to the resource by location. It isn't requesting anything from a server.

To be more specific about this SVG: This is a green check mark included in Bootstrap CSS to indicate valid form fields. Rails projects that use the SimpleForm gem with the `--bootstrap` install option will automatically use that check mark for valid form fields by applying the classes `is-valid` or `was-validated` to those fields. This behavior isn't limited to that setup, but it is a likely way to encounter it because (at least in my case) simple form is even using it on hidden fields, of which I have about 140 on one page. (I will likely try to stop it from doing that now.)

In my opinion, this shouldn't even be in the network tab because it isn't using a network. I suspect it is there so that everything that is specified as a URL or in place of one can be accounted for in one place. (If someone can explain better why it either *is* or *should* be there I can add that to this answer.)